# Missing kernel_blob.bin file in Release folder when build Flutter code into frameworks

Tags: ios, flutter, frameworks, flutter-module

I want to create a Flutter module, then I will embbed it to native iOS project.
I'm following **Option B** in this [document](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup) of Flutter to create a module.

As in the document, I executed this command:
`flutter build ios-framework --output=some/path/MyApp/Flutter/` to generate Flutter code into frameworks.

But when I imported **App.xcframework** and **Flutter.xcframework** (from same folder Release), I got this error:[image]

After researched, I followed this [document](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ios-project-migration) of Flutter, I updated *Thin Binary* script and add *Other Linker Flags*.

But when I build Flutter's code into frameworks, only **App.xcframework** in **Debug** folder have **kernel_blob.bin file**.

[image]
[image]

This is my flutter config:
[image]

How to make **App.xcframework** in **Release** folder have kernel_blob.bin file?
Thank in advance for your help